# Python Json extract value in specific format for metrics

Tags: python, json

I try to add value metrics from json file, the code works, but not in specif file that I want on file.json

```
with open('file.json') as fp:
     response = json.load(fp)
     for key, item in response.items():
         metric = Metric('duration_sec', 'Requests time taken in seconds', 'summary')
         metric.add_sample('seconds_count', value=item['a'], labels={})
         metric.add_sample('seconds_sum', value=item['b'], labels={})

         yield metric
```

I want to execute code but with this format code below

file.json

```
{
  "a": 10,
  "b": 20
}
{
  "a": 11,
  "b": 21
}
```

it works on :

```
{
    "0": {
        "a": 10,
        "b": 20
    },
    "1": {
        "a": 11,
        "b": 21
    }
}
```

Comment: your first format is not valid json

Comment: I don't think your requested format of file.json is a valid JSON format, so json.loads would not work. Do you just want a plain text file that contains dictionaries?

Comment: yes, but I can read with jq

Comment: okey, I add on common between values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the requested input file is not valid JSON, so the Python json module will not read it. However, you could do the following:

```
import re
import ast

with open("file.json", "r") as fp:
    # read in contents
    filedata = fp.read()

    # use re to extract data in dicts
    dictcontent = re.findall(r"\{([^{}]+)\}", filedata)

    # convert into dictionaries
    for content in dictcontent:
        subdict = ast.literal_eval("{" + content + "}")

        metric = Metric('duration_sec', 'Requests time taken in seconds', 'summary')
        metric.add_sample('seconds_count', value=subdict['a'], labels={})
        metric.add_sample('seconds_sum', value=subdict['b'], labels={})

        yield metric
```